# GENERATE THIS REPORT: main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, logging

When I call a simple block in the cms home page
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}

Comment: any solution form community?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of articles and StackExchange questions regarding constant logging in Magento ver. 2.2.0-dev, and while the levels vary, [This User](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3507#issuecomment-221278166) says it is not a problem in the github issue #3507, and it is reiterated on [Bountysource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/31125179-constant-critical-errors-in-system-log).  This may be worked out in the recent version, but it would also be worth looking into the log-levels:

```
Emergency – system is unusable.
Alert – action must be taken immediately. Example: entire website down, database unavailable, etc.
Critical – critical conditions. Example: application component unavailable, unexpected exception.
Error – runtime errors that do not require immediate action but should be typically logged and monitored.
Warning – exceptional occurrences that are not errors.
Notice – normal but significant events.
Info – interesting events.
Debug – detailed debug information.
```

Source: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/logging-system/